# SPDY for iOS with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, spdy, cocoa-spdy

I'm trying SPDY for iOS app, which currently uses AFNetworking (2.1.0) to handle HTTP requests. Server side, I'm using Google App Engine (Checked with [SPDYCheck](http://spdycheck.org/)) it's SPDY-friendly.

Here's how I integrated SPDY in my code.

I'm using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

```
@interface MyClient : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
```

And I embedded SPDY in `initWithBaseURL:`

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    // SPDY Config
    NSString *spdyURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@:443",url.scheme, url.host];

    [SPDYURLConnectionProtocol registerOrigin:spdyURL];
    ...
  }
```

Note that my url is with format `https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/` So I reformat it when passing to SPDY `registerOrigin:` spdyURL will look like `https://myapp.appspot.com:443`

I suppose that's all I need? But I wasn't able to send request after adding the SPDY code. Debug message showed the following error:

```
error response from api/users/v1/is_token_valid :
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain 
Code=-1001 
"The request timed out." 
UserInfo=0xdc2c250 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/users/v1/is_token_valid?
user_token=[a_token], 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/users/v1/is_token_valid?
user_token=[a_token], 
NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0xf270e60 "The request timed out."}
```

I have no clue at all. Hope someone with experience with SPDY on iOS could help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple's TLS implementation doesn't support NPN which is used by Google App Engine. You can read more about it in the [CocoaSPDY GitHub README](https://github.com/twitter/CocoaSPDY/blob/v1.0.0/README.md#a-note-on-npn).

You can't use CocoaSPDY with Google App Engine at this time.

Comment: @David Caunt Hello Sir Can I integrate CocoaSPDY for Mozilla FireFox ios App?

Answer (score 3):

It is true that Apple does not support NPN in default TLS implementation. However there are some SPDY libs using OpenSSL (which supports NPN).

Here is one on them:
https://github.com/locationlabs/SPDY-for-iPhone

Comment: did you try that before. I did find out the repo but not sure if it's reliable.

Comment: I tried to run it and it worked, but didn't use it in any project.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok for you?
I see that SPDY protocol support is now available in NSURLSession on OS X Yosemite and iOS 8 , and is Supported transparently by NSURLSession.
see details： https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/ [What's New in Foundation Networking]
But why it not work?
When i use CocoaSPDY, set manager.session.configuration.protocolClasses=@[[SPDYURLSessionProtocol class]]; it's ok;